# Get selected product options on configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, cart, addtocart

When I select the product options of configurable product on my website I get a pop-up with the added product. I want to show the selected options on the pop-up. I already got the following code which shows the label, but i can't seem the selected options to show in the pop-up.

Can someone tell me how to get the selected options on the pop-up.

For example:

I want 'Product A' with options: Color: black and size: 16. I add this product to cart and want to see the pop-up with both Color: black and Size: 16

```
<h4 class="product-name"></h4>
                <div class="options-wrapper">
                    <!-- Options: -->
                    <table class="options">
                        <?php

                        foreach ($_product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributes() as $attribute) {


                            echo '<td><td>' . $attribute->getLabel() . '</td><td>'. $attribute->getValue($_product).'</td></tr>';

                        }
                        ?>

                    </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: You can use the last added item and selected options from quote.

Comment: Sure. And do you have any idea how to get that?

Comment: Please check my answer from there you can get an idea how do you get the last added item.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it through following code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

$lastItem = $collection->getLastItem();
```

For options you can use the following code:

```
$options = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/quote_item_option_collection');
$options->addItemFilter($lastItem->getId());
```

Comment: Yes i understand this. But how can i get the values of the selected options when the latest added product is loaded?

Comment: Please check the updated answer.